# Referencing a StaticResource in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource, viewmodellocator

I have a UserControl which references a StaticResource which would normally be referenced in app.xaml and be fine... but my assembly is a library project so has no app.xaml. How do i reference this StaticResource now?

Here is the UserControl where I am trying to refence it

```
<UserControl 
   d:DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Type main:IViewModel}, 
   Converter={StaticResource viewModelLocator}}">
```

and here is where it would normally be in app.xaml

```
<Application xmlns:t="http://schemas.t.com/wpf" xmlns:app="clr-namespace:T.UI">
<Application.Resources>
    <t:ViewModelLocator 
       x:Key="viewModelLocator" 
       Container="{x:Static app:ConfigurationPlugin.Container}" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I just get the error message "viewModelLocator could not be resolved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding the resource to the UserControl's resources itself should do the trick; in fact pretty much every Wpf element has a `Resources` property.

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
  <t:ViewModelLocator x:Key="viewModelLocator"  
       Container="{x:Static app:ConfigurationPlugin.Container}" /> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought this was another way to do this but was getting an error message "Exception has been thrown by target invocation" so assumed I was wrong. I hate generic error messages that don't tell you what is wrong!!! I will keep plodding along trying to solve this.

Comment: for exceptions like these, hook up the debugger. When the exception occurs, you can get it's details, look at the tree of innerExceptions that should give you more info.

Comment: It runs fine without errors if i just run it. I get the error message when trying to populate my xaml design view with designtime data. This is however another problem not related to this question, so will leave it till another day :-) thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   ....
```

unless I don't understand your question.